# Detectar cambios en los roles que tienen los miembros del servidor

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Estoy intentando que mi bot de discord detecte cuando alguien mejora o deja de mejorar mi servidor.

Quiero que cuando al miembro se le añada el rol de "boost", el bot ejecute una función. Del mismo modo, si al miembro se le elimina dicho rol, que el bot ejecute otra función diferente.

Lo he intentado realizar mediante el evento `on_member_update()`, pero no consigo el funcionamiento esperado (no se ejecuta `print("Event works")`). ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Este es mi código, (en el evento `on_ready()` sí se realiza el `print()`):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="null!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Done")
    
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before,after):
    print("Event works")

bot.run("My bot Token")
```

Comment: que haz intentado?

Comment: el evento de on_member_update no funciono

use como
`from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="null!")
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before,after):
  print("Event Work")
bot.run("<filtered content>")
`

Comment: el bot ha cargado , pero al darle un rol a un usuario no escribio el "Event Work"

Comment: El código y toooooooooodas las aclaraciones van EN la pregunta, que puedes editar todas las veces que quieras. En los comentarios, seguir el código o revisar si está bien indentado es imposible

Comment: bien ya lo he editado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu idea de redefinir el evento [`on_member_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update) es correcta, ya que este evento es llamado cuando los roles del usuario cambian.

Esta función recibe 2 argumentos, que son el objeto [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.Member) antes y después de que a este se le aplicasen los cambios.

```
async def on_member_update(before : discord.Member, after : discord.Member):
```

Lo que tienes que hacer por tanto es comprobar si el rol en cuestión, que en tu caso es el [`premium_subcriber_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.premium_subscriber_role) del servidor (es decir, el rol de "boosteo"), ha sido añadido o eliminado de la lista de roles del miembro:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before : discord.Member, after : discord.Member):
    # Obtenemos el rol de "boosteo" del servidor.
    role = before.guild.premium_subscriber_role 

    # Comprobamos si se acaba de añadir el rol.
    if role not in before.roles and role in after.roles:
        print("¡Se ha añadido el rol!")

    # Comprobamos si se acaba de eliminar el rol.
    if role in before.roles and role not in after.roles:
        print("¡Se ha eliminado el rol!")
```

---

**Para `discord.py 2.0` y versiones superiores:**

Como se puede ver en la [documentación](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update), el evento `on_member_update()` requiere que [`Intents.member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.Intents.members) se encuentre activado.

Este es, junto a [`Intents.presences`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.Intents.presences) e [`Intents.message_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.Intents.message_content) los únicos `intents` que no se activan cuando se crean los [`intents` por defecto](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.Intents.default).

Habría que tener esto en cuenta al inicializar el bot para poder detectar los cambios de los miembros que desencadenan el evento:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="null!", intents=intents)
```